# .setBackgroundColor() not working outside click event

Tags: java, android, events, view

I have a seemingly simple problem.  I am working with imagebuttons inside a linearlayout which is inside a scrollview.  I have set an onClickListener for one of the buttons which switches the color to red then transparent and then back again.  I have tried calling performClick() and manually coding a routine to fire when a condition is met.  The problem I am having is no matter how I try to do this the method(s) that are calling .setBackgroundColor() are all exiting when it's called.  I don't even get to see a return statement in my Log.  here is the code.  I am sure this is a simple fix but I am not familiar very familiar with these things.  Also I am not using any XML and would like to avoid it if possible so please keep that in mind when posting suggestions.  Thanks in advance!

I will try to clarify what I am trying to accomplish.  I am attempting to emulate the events that are fired during a click event WITHOUT a click event happening.  I have tried this with performClick() and in the way I have here.  In both cases I have the call to .setBackgroundColor() not firing and prematurely exiting the method that is calling it and it is called in.

After messing around a bit I found that the method will fire the setBackgroundColor() AND continue the method when I use Color.RED when it is already the color red.  If I try any other colors it doesn't work.  So it appears to not want to change the color in this fashion.  Any ideas anyone?

here is the handler:

```
IBFireBall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "in onClick");
                if (Fireball.activated) {
                    Fireball.activated = false;
                    AbilityWidget.IBFireBall.setBackgroundColor(0);
                    Log.d(TAG, "was activated");
                } else {
                    Level.fireBall = new Fireball(context);
                    Fireball.activated = true;
                    AbilityWidget.IBFireBall.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    Log.d(TAG, "wasn't activated");
                }

            }

        });
```

here is the other method Log only prints out 1 and 2:

```
public static void resetButton(String id) {

    if (id.equals("Fireball")) {

        if (Fireball.activated) {
            Log.d(TAG,"inside resetbutton 1");
            Fireball.activated = false;
            Log.d(TAG,"inside resetbutton2" );
            AbilityWidget.IBFireBall.setBackgroundColor(0);
            Log.d(TAG,"inside resetbutton4" );

        } else {

            Level.fireBall = new Fireball(context);
            Fireball.activated = true;
            AbilityWidget.IBFireBall.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Log.d(TAG, "wasn't activated");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (id == "Fireball")`: never compare strings with `==`. Use `equals()` instead.

Comment: Thank you that is something I completely forgot about.  Still the comparison goes through and that isn't what is preventing the setbackgroundcolor() from firing.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First never use ``` "=="`` to compare Objects, use ```.equals()`.

**2.** You are Not calling the `resetButton()` method from the `onClick()`, how will this method be invoked, if its not called.

Comment: this is part of the ui for a game.  There is a thread running in my update method for one of my classes it asks if I am ready to switch the button back it then calls AbilityWidget.resetButton("Fireball").  I have also from outside the AbilityWidget class and inside tried using performClick() this causes the same issue. thank you for the == vs .equals() I have already made that change.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem lies in threading.  You can't update UI outside UI thread.  Case closed :) I'll link some documentation on subject later.